# Visual Studio 2010 devenv.exe qtappwrapper.exe

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, qt4

I had installed QT for some project sometime back but don't use it now(may need it later). I noticed that whenever I start Visual Studio 2010, it hogs my RAM. Is it possible to disable loading it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to use the [Visual Studio Add-ins Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwdatdwh.aspx) to disable the Qt Visual Studio add-in.